# getting linkage error : X11

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Getting linkage error: XInitTreads unresolved in libsl_zed.so
In the past I was able to simple put the X11 linkage in my CMakeList and that worked but now this seems to  have stopped working. Any ideas what can be causing this issue. I should also mention that this is being compiled on the Jetson tk1 (arm7).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)

project(zed_wrapper)

###############################################################################
## Options
option( DEBUG_ACTIVE "Enable Debug build" ON )

if(DEBUG_ACTIVE)
    MESSAGE( "Debug compilation active" )
    set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
else()
    MESSAGE( "Release compilation active" )
    set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Release)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()
###############################################################################

find_package(ZED 0.9 REQUIRED)
find_package(X11 REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV 2.4 COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  image_transport
  roscpp
  rosconsole
  sensor_msgs
  cv_bridge
  dynamic_reconfigure
)

generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  cfg/Zed.cfg
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    roscpp
    rosconsole
    sensor_msgs
    opencv2
    cv_bridge
    image_transport
    dynamic_reconfigure
)

###############################################################################
# INCLUDES

# Specify locations of header files.
include_directories(
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
    ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${ZED_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(${X11_LIBRARY_DIR})
link_directories(${ZED_LIBRARY_DIR})
link_directories(${CUDA_LIBRARY_DIRS})
link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

###############################################################################

###############################################################################
# EXECUTABLE

add_definitions(-std=c++11)# -m64) #-Wall)


add_executable(
  zed_wrapper_node
  src/zed_wrapper_node.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
        zed_wrapper_node
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${X11_LIBRARIES}
        ${ZED_LIBRARIES}
    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_nppi_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_npps_LIBRARY}
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        ${PCL_LIBRARIES}  
    )

add_dependencies(zed_wrapper_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
###############################################################################

#Add all files in subdirectories of the project in
# a dummy_target so qtcreator have access to all files
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE extra_files ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*)
add_custom_target(dummy_${PROJECT_NAME} SOURCES ${extra_files})
Status API Training Shop Blog About Pricing
© 2016 GitHub, Inc. Terms Privacy Security Contact Help
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228303/getting-linkage-error-:-x11/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2016-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-05**:
It looks like you're trying to compile this package: https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper and you've opened a ticket there with more info: https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/issues/23

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-05**:
It looks like your version of libsl_zed.so might have missing dependencies or might have become broken during a recent update. Is libsl_zed.so something that you installed and built from source? Have you upgraded your system recently?

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2016-03-05**:
I did a general update of the system before taking a new version of zed-ros-wrapper. Prior to that it compiled  . Not sure if libsl_zed.so was updated at that time. I did open an issue on this on github and also send an email to zedlabs tech support. Have not heard back yet on either.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2016-03-05**:
If libsl_zed.so had a missing dependency should not including the link library as I have done resolve the reference? I was wondering if there was a circular reference somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem determined to be zedlab s issue with the Jetson TK1.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2016-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-06**:
Please update your answer with a detailed description of your solution, so that the next person doesn't have the same trouble that you did.